# React Native 0.71.1 version throws error after upgrade

Tags: react-native

I have upgraded my React Native to the latest version which is `0.71.1`. After upgrading my project to the latest version it's throwing error when i try to run the project which is like:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.1.
> Required by:
> project :app
> project :app > project :react-native-community_slider
> project :app > project :react-native-picker_picker

Now, what can i do to solve this issue ? I have deleted node module and installed again. Upgraded the dependencies too. But not sure what i need to do at this point. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm have problems with version of the React Native .
O Solve this with making downgrade version: using

npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2

Perhabs it help you!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).